# parse all col names and create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

```
date     red,heavy,new  blue,light,old
1-2-20   320             120
2-3-20   220             125
```

I want to iterate through all rows and columns such that I can I can parse the column names and use them as values for new columns. I want to get a data of this format:

I want dates to be repeated. The 'value' col is from the original table.

```
date     color           weight   condition.  value
1-2-20   red             heavy     new        320
1-2-20   blue            light.    old.       120
2-3-20   red.            heavy     new.       220
```

I tried this and it worked for when I only had one column

```
colName = df_retransform.columns[1]

lst = colName.split(",")
color = lst[0]
weight = lst[1]
condition = lst[2]


df_retransform.rename(columns={colName: 'value'}, inplace=True)
df_retransform['color'] = color
df_retransform['weight'] = weight
df_retransform['condition'] = condition
```

but I am unable to modify it such that it I can do it for all columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

```
 # install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git
 import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index="date", 
                names_to=("color", "weight", "condition"), 
                names_sep=",")

date    color   weight  condition   value
0   1-2-20  red     heavy   new     320
1   2-3-20  red     heavy   new     220
2   1-2-20  blue    light   old     120
3   2-3-20  blue    light   old     125
```

You pass the names of the new column to `names_to`, and specify the separator (`,`) in `names_sep`.

If you want it returned in order of appearance, you could pass boolean `True` to the `sort_by_appearance` argument:

```
df.pivot_longer(
    index="date",
    names_to=("color", "weight", "condition"),
    names_sep=",",
    sort_by_appearance=True,
)


    date    color   weight  condition   value
0   1-2-20  red     heavy   new     320
1   1-2-20  blue    light   old     120
2   2-3-20  red     heavy   new     220
3   2-3-20  blue    light   old     125
```

Comment: tried this but I get the same df as before - any ideas why this could happen?

Comment: Strange. I am using the exact data you shared. Does the code work for the same data you shared?

Comment: is it possible that this method might skip some rows/dates? Maybe because of some null values?

Comment: The problem earlier was that I wasn't setting it to ```df_retransform = df_retransform.pivot_longer```and was printing the df again separately. Fixed now. But there are missing values

Comment: Mind sharing data that includes the missing rows?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is for using and drop column `variable`, last change order of columns names if necessary:

First you can test if all columns without data has 2 `,`:

```
print ([col for col in df.columns if col.count(',') != 2])
['date'] 


df = df.melt('date')
df[['color', 'weight', 'condition']] = df.pop('variable').str.split(',', expand=True)

df = df[['date', 'color', 'weight', 'condition', 'value']]
print (df)
     date color weight condition  value
0  1-2-20   red  heavy       new    320
1  2-3-20   red  heavy       new    220
2  1-2-20  blue  light       old    120
3  2-3-20  blue  light       old    125
```

Or use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series`, then split and recreate new all levels for new columns:

```
print (df)
    date  red,heavy,new  blue,light,old
0  1-2-20            320             NaN
1     NaN            220           125.0

s = df.set_index('date').stack(dropna=False)
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, *j.split(',')) for i, j in s.index], 
                                    names=['date', 'color', 'weight', 'condition'])
df = s.reset_index(name='value')
print (df)

     date color weight condition  value
0  1-2-20   red  heavy       new  320.0
1  1-2-20  blue  light       old    NaN
2     NaN   red  heavy       new  220.0
3     NaN  blue  light       old  125.0
```

Comment: Did you just use `pop` to select and remove a column at the same time...?  Impressive

Comment: @MarkWang - Yes, it is nice shorcut ;)

Comment: @a125 - after `.melt()` is created `variable` column name, so I split it and remove. Alternative is instead  `df[['color', 'weight', 'condition']] = df.pop('variable').str.split(',', expand=True)` using `df[['color', 'weight', 'condition']] = df['variable'].str.split(',', expand=True)` and then `df = df.drop('variable', axis=1)`

Comment: I tried the same thing but it gives me ```KeyError: 'variable'```

Comment: @a125 - Do you use `df = df.melt('date')` before?

Comment: @a125 - I think problem should be not always 3 columns in columns names (it means not always 2 times `,`)

Comment: I doubt that's the case - since the ```,```were added programatically

Comment: @a125 - I add to answer `print ([col for col in df.columns if col.count(',') != 2])`, for you also return only `['date']` ?

Comment: @a125 - Both solutions failed?

Comment: Just checked - second one seems to work, I don't understand it much. Could you explain in steps? Like the *j part? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @a125 - Sure,  `*` it is pure python unpack opearator, in `s.index` are 2 levels, first filled by dates and second by joined values by `,`. I think spit second level and add first one, so is used list comprehension with `(i, *j.split(','))` it means it take `1-2-20   red,heavy,new` and after split with `*` create tuples with 4 values like  `( 1-2-20,red,heavy,new)`. It is used for MultiIndex from tuples, so are created 4 levles used for 4 columns.

Comment: @a125 - Hmmm, this error means there are not only `2 times ,`, there are 1,3,4 or more in some column :(

Comment: @a125 - Testting and you are right! If missing values then removed, for prevent it need change `.stack()` to `.stack(dropna=False)`

Comment: @a125 - Is possible more specify which values/ rows are removed? Because this problem seems data related, in sample data working well.